# Does padding of relatively positioned element affect (0,0) of absolutely positioned child element?

Tags: css

This is a CSS issue that doesn't make sense to me..

Right now I have something like this:

```
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child {
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  position:absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

The child right now disregards padding of parent. This seems counter-intuitive to me. Am I missing a quick fix (I can't add padding/margin to child)? Did I mess up the DOCTYPE?

Thanks!
Matt Mueller

Answer (score 1):

Since you have specified position absolute for the child element this behavior is the correct one. The child will be positioned absolutely with the left and top value.

> In the absolute positioning model, a
>   box is explicitly offset with respect
>   to its containing block. ***It is removed***
>   ***from the normal flow entirely*** (it has
>   no impact on later siblings). An
>   absolutely positioned box establishes
>   a new containing block for normal flow
>   children and absolutely (but not
>   fixed) positioned descendants.
>   However, the contents of an absolutely
>   positioned element do not flow around
>   any other boxes. They may obscure the
>   contents of another box (or be
>   obscured themselves), depending on the
>   stack levels of the overlapping boxes.

[Visual Formatting model - Absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#absolute-positioning)